# Listeners reset to HTTP after every deployment

Tags: azure, kubernetes

My setup is this: Azure AKS with application gateway as the ingress. I have a `deploy.yml` and a `service.yml` describing my service, and I have a tls secret set up properly.

Problem is this, I can use the Azure portal to manually create an HTTPS listener with the secret I created, and everything works just fine. How do I know it's working properly? I use curl with the https protocol and I get the desired result. Also I look at the pod log and see the request coming in properly.

**However** as soon as I update a deployment (using `kubectl apply -f deploy.yml`) all my manual work is reset and the listeners are recreated using HTTP, and I have to redo all the work: Create an HTTPS listener, move the rules to the new listener, etc.

This is my `ingress.yml`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: "/"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - my.website.com
      secretName: my-secret
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api1/*
        backend:
          serviceName: my-first-svc
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /api2/*
        backend:
          serviceName: my-first-svc
          servicePort: 8081
```

And this is my `deploy.yml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-pod
        image: myuser/my-app:v10
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 6666
        env:
          - name: ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: app-secrets
                key: connection-string
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /api/values
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 10
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

**UPDATE** Found the answer, the problem is with the `ingress.yml` file, I was missing a `host` entry in the first `spec.rules` object:

```
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - my.website.com
      secretName: my-secret
  rules:
  - host: my.website.com  # <----- THIS WAS MISSING!
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api1/*
        backend:
```

Comment: It's likely happening because when you apply it triggers the appgateway controller to go apply the config you have just set - thereby wiping any manual settings. What stops you building the https config you need into your ingress definition?

Comment: I just don't know how to do that, I'm a newbie

Comment: You have a TLS spec in the above, so what is it about that config that you are having to manually change?

Comment: Azure does things on its own every time I apply a yaml change. Specifically, it resets the listener configuration back to HTTP

Comment: Found the solution! I was missing a `host` field in the first `rules` `http` entry (next to `paths`)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting OP's answer for better visibility:

> **UPDATE** Found the answer, the problem is with the `ingress.yml` file, I was missing a `host` entry in the first `spec.rules` object:
>
> ```
> spec:
>   tls:
>     - hosts:
>       - my.website.com
>       secretName: my-secret
>   rules:
>   - host: my.website.com  # <----- THIS WAS MISSING!
>     http:
>       paths:
>       - path: /api1/*
>         backend:
> ```